# ejabberd and "call to undefined function pgsql:squery"

Tags: postgresql, ejabberd

I'm using ejabberd 18.04 on debian 9 and postgresql. I can create a user and I see it in the users table. I can log in through the client and through webadmin. Hence ejabberd and postgresql work. But when I try to add a user to the roster (module mod_roster is connected), I get the following output:

```
...
11:49:35.760 [error] gen_fsm <0.397.0> in state session_established terminated with reason: call to undefined function pgsql:squery(<0.418.0>, [<<"begin;">>], 59000)
11:49:35.760 [error] CRASH REPORT Process <0.397.0> with 0 neighbours exited with reason: call to undefined function pgsql:squery(<0.418.0>, [<<"begin;">>], 59000) in p1_fsm:terminate/8 line 760
11:49:35.761 [error] Supervisor 'ejabberd_sql_sup_192.168.56.111' had child 6 started with ejabberd_sql:start_link(<<"192.168.56.111">>, 30000) at <0.397.0> exit with reason call to undefined function pgsql:squery(<0.418.0>, [<<"begin;">>], 59000) in context child_terminated
11:49:35.761 [error] gen_fsm <0.401.0> in state session_established terminated with reason: call to undefined function pgsql:squery(<0.422.0>, [<<"begin;">>], 59000)
11:49:35.765 [error] CRASH REPORT Process <0.401.0> with 0 neighbours exited with reason: call to undefined function pgsql:squery(<0.422.0>, [<<"begin;">>], 59000) in p1_fsm:terminate/8 line 760
11:49:35.776 [error] Supervisor 'ejabberd_sql_sup_192.168.56.111' had child 10 started with ejabberd_sql:start_link(<<"192.168.56.111">>, 30000) at <0.401.0> exit with reason call to undefined function pgsql:squery(<0.422.0>, [<<"begin;">>], 59000) in context child_terminated
...
```

What does it mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose, the error has the answer:

> terminated with reason: call to undefined function **pgsql:squery**

This mean that you call undefined function. You need to check:

1. is included a module or app **pgsql** in your project
2. in app or module **pgsql** try find function **squery**
3. Also, need to check documentation of app **pgsql**, possibly the feature is deprecated or has been removed from versions which you are trying to use.

Perhaps this function is in **pgsql**, but it is used in the wrong way, by eg:  let's say there is an exported function of the **squery** with 2 arguments, but in your project it is called with 3 arguments, in this case you will also get an error like - *terminated with reason: call to undefined function pgsql:squery*.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue on my Debian Stretch machine. Turned out that the Ejabberd version that I was using was not compatible with the `erlang-p1-pgsql` package that was installed.

The `ejabberd` package was from Debian stretch-backports while the `erlang-p1-pgsql` package was from the main repo. A quick update / install from the backports repo did the trick:

`apt-get install -t stretch-backports erlang-p1-pgsql`

Then restart Ejabberd and the error should be fixed :-)

*(I'm writing this a more complete answer in case somebody has the same problem like me)*